# How to stay logged in when parsing pages with PHP?

Tags: php, parsing, session, account

I'm trying to parse site, for example YouTube. I logged into my Google account on my computer. For parsing I use PHP and PHP simple HTML dom parser. This is my code.

```
<?php
    include '../dom_parser/simple_html_dom.php';

    $html = file_get_html("https://youtube.com");
    echo $html;
```

As expected, I got basic markup without styles. But this is not what I want to parse. I got the YouTube homepage and I want to get the YouTube homepage linked to my Google account.

Therefore, I would like to know how to parse a web page (not just YouTube) on which the user is logged in on his computer. If this is not possible with PHP, you can suggest alternative methods.

Comment: You will be a lot better off using youtube API. Any other solution will tend to break often, and might violate terms of use.  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3

Comment: I want to use that system not for YouTube. As I understood, there is no universal solution for this issue, but YouTube provides its API. It's good for YouTube, but it will work only for it.